# Looking for programmable controller for linear actuators for use in a standing desk

Tags: usb, bluetooth, automation, ergonomics

I'm trying to build a sit-stand desk solution with motors that can be controlled by a computer.  I've found some good instructions for building your own [electric height adjustable desk here](http://www.instructables.com/id/Electric-Height-Adjustable-Desk/), however, it does not talk about interfacing with a computer.

I'd like to create software on a desktop, laptop, mobile phone, or tablet that interfaces with the motors of the desk, allowing them to be controlled to raise, lower the desk automatically to two or more preset locations as well as being triggered automatically under certain circumstances.  I imagine the motors would be connected to a controller that knows their position and can change their position to a known second position and the controller might have a bluetooth capability for integration with a computing device to control it.  Alternatively, perhaps a USB connection could be used.

**What are some options for controllers that could provide this capability?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you'd have excellent luck with the [Raspberry Pi A+](https://www.adafruit.com/product/2266) for ~$25. It has excellent documentation, some preexisting [servo driver software](https://github.com/richardghirst/PiBits/tree/master/ServoBlaster), and integrated GPIO pins, which are the things you solder the controller wires from your motors to. It does NOT run a real-time environment, so stutter might occur, but for your use case that might not matter. At only $25, it makes sense to try this first and then add something like an [Arduino Uno](https://www.adafruit.com/products/50) if stuttering IS a problem, since the Arduino will likely need to communicate with the Pi anyway. The big draw here is really the documentation; this is an incredibly well-documented platform with a lot of active users.